# Use local image for default avatar

Tags: functions, avatar, gravatar

I tried putting this snippet in my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'newgravatar' );

function newgravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
    $myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_avatar.png';
    $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Locale";
    return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

A new avatar appears in Options-Discussion. Problem is it's not local at all.. the avatar is taken from `http://i1.wp.com/mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/default_avatar.png`.

So it passes through `i1.wp.com` anyway.. how can I just have a friggin LOCAL link?

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) );` return?  Also: consider using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [`get_template_stylesheet_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead.

Comment: var_dump returns `string(50) "http://website.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme"`

Comment: Hmmm.  Have you tried disabling all plugins to see if one of them is causing this?  I'm wondering if Jetpack (because when I surf to `i1.wp.com` in my browser, the favicon is the Jetpack logo) or any CDN plugins might be the cause.

Comment: I disabled all plugins (jetpack included). Cleared all caches (server, browser). No luck.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have the Photon module enabled in the Jetpack plugin. That module routes your images through WordPress.com's CDN. If you don't want this to happen, disable the Photon module in Jetpack.

Comment: Nice catch!! ;)

Comment: I talked too early.. actually photon is disabled.. could it be it messed anyway with some WP function?

Comment: Uhm... I even tried disabling Jetpack completely.. no luck!

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin of some kind? Clear the cache.

Comment: No plugin either :(

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking up how to do this myself and that same function shown above everyone keeps suggesting isn't working, perhaps due to a recent update to WP's codebase, I'm not entirely sure. It's a little hackish and it involves editing core files (not good) but it's a work-around solution. Here's the steps:

1. Use the same function specified in the original post
2. Open /wp-includes/pluggable.php and search for "function get_avatar", this should get you to where the function is defined in the file
3. Scroll down to just above where the first IMG tag is outputted, you should see this:

   ```
   $out = str_replace( '&#038;', '&amp;', esc_url( $out ) );

   $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$out}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
   ```
4. Just under `$out`, add `$out = $default;` This basically passes the default image source url (stored in the options table)

So it should look like this:

```
    $out = str_replace( '&#038;', '&amp;', esc_url( $out ) );
    $out = $default;

    $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$out}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
} else {
    $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$default}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
}

return apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
```

Again, this isn't ideal obviously because the next time you update WordPress, you'll lose this change. But for the moment it works.

To future visitors looking to not modify core files, you may want to look into filtering the WP function `get_avatar`. It seems to do so would require modifying the  string supplied in the filter with a regular expression to remove the gravatar domain. I attempted it but suck at regex. :P

Comment: Thanks!!! Would be great if someone could maybe create a snippet to put on functions.php to replicate this.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad my time spent doing trial and error could be useful. Like I mentioned, it seems like very possible to use one function instead of editing WP's core by using regular expressions to filter out the gravatar nonsense passed by the get_avatar filter. Maybe someone more gifted with PHP can lend a hand on that. Ideally this would be submitted as a bug in the WP code trac (I think I read somewhere it already is, not sure though).